# Apache Kafka consume events from different topics in specific order

Tags: concurrency, java-8, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Let's say, I have topicA, topicB and topicC, both topic segregated by separate event types, based on domain entities. topicA operate with eventA only, topicB keeps eventB, topicC operates with eventC only. All events relate to each other by business domain but produced by separate microservices and should be processed in specific order.

The question is, how to using Apache Kafka introduce consuming events in specific order, eventA then wait for receiving eventB then when eventC received consume all of them.

Appreciate any feedback, any questions are welcome.

Some notes:
Kafka Streams is a good approach, but restricted by company policies.

Also, I've looked through [Join Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join-pattern) but haven't found any reliable approaches for implementation.

Comment: Martin Kleppmann has a great article  on this subject: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2018/01/18/event-types-in-kafka-topic.html

Comment: I'm curious what these "company policies" are that allow you to use the Producer/Consumer API, but not Streams

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi thanks for the great article. I don't have a big experience with kafka and microservices on production, but what are the practices to use kafka on production, I mean is it OK of having dozens topics per every business entity, or everybody keeps small number of topics?

Comment: Check https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster to find out how to choose number of topics and partitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, there are many approaches to solve the problem. Here are couple, that I can suggest:

- ***Introduce correlation ID***, that will link events from topics A, B and C. Then, use correlation ID in following manner:

  1. Services A, B and C produce events to corresponding topics, but related events have the same correlation ID
  2. Service D consumes events from separate topics. Each time it receives event from any topic, service D either inserts event data to database by correlation ID, or performs some action if all data is received.

  For example, when service D receives event C it first issues query to check if there is record in database with correlation ID from event C:

  - if there is no record, then incoming event C is stored,
  - if some record already exist, then service D checks whether event C is the last one needed to consume all data and either performs final action, or inserts event C to the database.

  And so on for each consumed event.
- ***Chain services that produce events*** (A, B and C). For example, chain can be formed in following manner:

  1. Service A produces event to topic A
  2. Service B consumes event from topic A, and produces event to topic B (possibly, aggregating events A and B)
  3. Service C consumes event from topic B, and produces event to topic C (possibly, aggregating events A, B and C)
  4. Finally, service D consumes event from topic C (possibly, aggregated with A, B and C) and executes required action.

  Variation of this approach (without aggregating events on each intermediate stage), would be to chain services and listen for last event in the chain. When last event is consumed, then issue Kafka pull to corresponding topics to get events produced by other services.

Comment: Thank you that works for me. I had a similar solution to use a correlationID, but also we need to use a single topic for such events to process in specific order

Answer (score 3):

If events are related to each other then they should go to one topic. So microservice-1 should push eventA with (key, value) & label (eventA). In the same way, microservice-2 and microservice-3 should push data to a common topic.

This would help you at consumer side.

Comment: Interesting idea. What do you mean by "label" in this case, a messageId? One more question, if we have one common topic but 4 partitions for example, and  4 different event consumers with different groupIds... we will have events duplication, aren't we?

Comment: You can use Header (https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/header/Header.html) to enrich a message. FYI, Messages with similar key will go to a same partition (kind of like hashmap in java).

Comment: You need to commit offsets manually at consumer side. You consumer should find a message with label A ,skip messages until it finds related message with label B, skip messages until it finds related message with label C. This will only work if related events have similar key. For exmaple, billId can be a key if events are "bill created", "notification sent" & "payment received".

Comment: If you're using kafka, you'll have to constrain your topic to never use more than one partition, or to have the producers all use a common partitioning scheme for partitioning the messages when sending to the broker.  Otherwise, your messages may be received and processed out of order. 

This would also couple microservice-1, microservice-2, and microservice-3 in a way that may constrain each of those services in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Such solution is good when services get developed by the same team or teams in the same project.. but it requires a lot of work when it depends to different projects. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about about ordering the consumption of messages between different topics, then the first option would be to have one consumer produce a message, feeding the next consumer (these consumers may or may not be part of the same process):

consumerA processes message -> consumerA puts new message on a different topic -> consumerB picks up that new message and processes -> consumerB puts new message on a second topics -> etc... etc..

I would not be surprised if streams is essentially doing this or a similar process under the hood. Any other kind of interface for inter-process communication could be used instead: RDP, memory-mapped files, mutex, pipes; take your pick.

Unless as a last resort, I would try to avoid putting different events on the same topic. When you put multiple events on a single queue/topic, you constrain your consumers in a couple ways:

1. Your contracts are now tightly coupled for both events. To change the shape of just one of the events on that single topic, your consumers have to dynamically deserialize those events based on metadata (a magic number, key-value, etc.)
2. Your consumption patterns may be less efficient. What if I'm just interested in one of those events? I have to read the event and then throw it out if its not the one I'm looking for.

A real-life example of this is in amusement parks. Let's say you have two types of amusement park visitors: Fast-Pass and Standard customers. Your business rules state that Fast-Pass customers get to skip the line ahead of standard customers.

If you merge them into a single queue/topic, how do you do that? The answer is priority queueing; you ask everyone who joins in line if they're fast pass, which is prone to mistakes and is inefficient (this is priority queueing; it can work, but it may not be the best solution). Most amusement parks solved this by setting up two separate queues (one for each type of customer [event/message]). Now they can feed customers into two separate attendants (one FastPass one Standard), or they might have one attendant do both queues, emptying the fast-pass queue first.

At the end of the day, it depends on your constraints: is it 10 messages a day, or 1 billion, do you require immediate consistency or eventual consistency, is it on an IoT device?

Comment: Streams is indeed doing that for the stateful operations

Comment: Streams indeed appropriate for such operations, but in open source library, streams have a few defects which critical for the system. So you propose to have a separate topic to keep aggregation results?

Comment: If you're already using topicA, topicB, and topicC, I don't think adding topicD and topicE introduces new constraints.  And yes, we've used separate topics as aggregation results before.